# Nested UIStackViews in UITableViewCell not working with constraints

Tags: swift, uitableview, interface-builder

I have a simple table view controller.  Section 0 will be a single cell with a couple of labels, textfields, and a few buttons.  I wanted to use stack views to layout the fields neatly. The moment I add any constraints I get the whole thing off the cell and not visible. The one button that is alway visible isn't even the correct width. The cell height is plenty large enough to hold it. It looks perfect in the interface builder, and has no errors or conflicting constraints.  What am I missing?
Then image with the fields all there is without any constraints.

**In the Interface builder**

[image: [1]]

---

**ScreenShot**

[image: [2]]

Comment: I don't know what happened to my images.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.